# Cannot get image from public folder on Server in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm saving my uploaded image in public folder like

> public/user/user_img_1.jpg

and saving

```
/user/user_img_1.jpg
```

in my database column as image path. Now when i get it 
`<img src="{{ $userData->thumb_img }}" alt="Profile Image" />` , the image shows on localhost but on server the image is not found. $userData variables stores the path.

Comment: See what's url it resolves to on both machines. Also please specify correct laravel version in tags, not all available.

Comment: /user/user_img_1.jpg this is what i'm getting in the image tag.

Comment: have you uploaded image at production server ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut: Yes i have uploaded

Comment: If you don't mind can you share live site url  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do any one step :

Put all your files (img) into the public folder.

```
<img src="/user/{{ $userData->thum_img }}" alt="Profile Image" />
```

Or, Use `asset` helper :

```
<img src="/user/{{ asset($userData->thum_img) }}" alt="Profile Image" />
```

where `user_img_1.jpg`  is path of your content.

Comment: I have tried this  {{ asset($userData->thumb_img) }} but it only displays text

Comment: @user3653474 , I think you had image name as `user_img_1.jpg` and not `/user/user_img_1.jpg` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use asset function to generate a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request.

In your case that would be: `<img src="{{ asset($userData->thumb_img) }} alt="Profile Image" />`

Answer (score 1):

We need to give permissions in Laravel for uploading and fetching the images.

Suppose you have saved the image in the public folder under the user folder. 
Directory Path: public/user/

And save the image in Database like below:
key: thumb_img
value: "public/user/imagename.jpg"

{{ asset($userData->thumb_img) }}

***You need to use the asset function for fetching the image.***

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: <img src="{{ asset($userData->thumb_img) }}"/>